# Finding the maximum without differentiation

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima, cubics

> [image]

I have this problem that needs to be solved as if I was a GCSE student.

After cutting a square of length $x$ from each corner, the volume of the open box would be $V= x(10-2x)(10-2x)$. We want to find the value of $x$ so that this volume is maximised. The ordinary solution would be to differentiate the cubic expression and find that the maximum point is at $x=\frac{5}{3}$. However, only knowledge up to KS4 (UK Year 11) may be used to solve it. Would the only appropriate approach be to use an iterative method (trial and error) to obtain an approximate value?

Comment: If your question in inside a image, it can not be search indexed. :(

Answer (score 3):

Note that by [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#The_inequality),
$$4V=4x(10−2x)(10−2x)\leq \left(\frac{4x+(10−2x)+(10−2x)}{3}\right)^3=\left(\frac{20}{3}\right)^3.$$
Equality holds, and the maximum value of $V$ is attained, when $4x=10-2x$, i.e. for $x=5/3$.

P.S. Actually what you need is just a particular case of AM-GM inequality: for $a,b\geq 0$,
$$ab^2\leq \left(\frac{a+2b}{3}\right)^3 \tag{1}$$
that is, after some standard calculations, equivalent to
$$(a+8b)(a-b)^2\geq 0$$
which holds. Equality is satisfied when $a=b$. Now apply $(1)$ with $a=4x$ and $b=10-2x$.

Comment: I don’t think this fits the requirement of being ks4 knowledge unfortunately.

Comment: Yes unfortunately this inequality isn't on the GCSE syllabus. Out of interest though, could you explain how you get from $4V=\frac{20}{3}^3$ at the maximum to knowing $4x=10-2x$ at the maximum?

Comment: @Refnom95 OK. I gave you an elementary proof of what you need.

Comment: @Jamminermit Do you think that now the proof fits the requirement of being ks4 knowledge?